# Changing Windows update settings by cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-update, regedit

Is there any way to change the Windows Update schedule from cmd? Or change any reg entry or something similar so that the change can be added in a batch file so it can be run and make the settings on multiple PCs?

Like schedule the Windows update everyday at 23:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears so, but it depends on if you're a domain or not. I also understand your question to actually ask what the settings are (and that you're fine with writing a batch file so I'll leave that out).

Check out the options here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto
 Update\AUOptions`

In here, there is a ScheduledInstallDay and a ScheduledInstallTime

[image]

[More general details (and source):](https://serverfault.com/questions/322682/can-you-change-windows-update-settings-via-command-line)